# Sort multi-dimensional array BUT do not reassign top-level keys

Tags: php, usort

array

```
$tagHolder[$row['id']] = array(


        "name" => $row['name'],
        "primary" => $row['primary'],
        "child" => $row['child'],
        "order" => $row['order']

    );
```

usort function

```
function sortAsc($x, $y){
if ( $x['order'] == $y['order'] )
 return 0;
else if ( $x['order'] < $y['order'] )
 return -1;
else
 return 1;
}
```

Will order by 'order' BUT will not keep the original `$row['id']` keys, instead it reassigns the first prosition as 0 and so on. How can I make the sort function sort but keep the `$row['key']` untouched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`uasort`](http://php.net/uasort) instead of [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) to keep the key association.